# using optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin led to remove all the '-webkit-transform'

Tags: node.js, webpack

My enviroment: webpack v3.6., node v6.11.0, and npm 5.7.1.

I found all the autoprefix style were removed after adding the `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`. I guess the `cssnano` is the problem but I don't know how to fix it after I tried many ways like `define BROWSERSLIST_CONFIG`.

webpack.config.js:

```
plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': '"production"'
    }), new UglifyJSPlugin(), new ExtractTextPlugin({
        filename: (getPath) => {
            return getPath('css/[name].[contenthash:7].css').replace('css/js/common', 'css/common')
        },
        allChunks: true
    }), new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
        cssProcessorOptions: {
            safe: true
        },
    }), new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()]
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts from your webpack config file.

Comment: `plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': '"production"'
        }),
        new UglifyJSPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: (getPath) => {
            return getPath('css/[name].[contenthash:7].css').replace('css/js/common', 'css/common')
          },
          allChunks: true
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: { safe: true },
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
      ]`